# SDK manager in Android Studio not available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

I installed Android Studio through the terminal, opened the studio and wanted to run the SDK manager, but this is what I have:
[image: SDK manager is unclickable]

As you see, the *SDK Manager* is unclickable. As I read online, the manager should be downloaded and installed only if you use Eclipse.

So, do I need do download it (because [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) it doesn't look like I need to add it additionally, in case I use Android Studio).

Any suggestions on how to approach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue and resolved as follow :

1. downloading stand alone SDK
   (https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. expand in SDK directory under main directory of android-studio
3. set the SDK path from Welcome to Android Studio window -> Project defaults -> Project
   structure -> Android SDK location